# Memory Arrays Should Have Push() And Pop()

Tags: solidity, memory

Dynamic memory arrays currently cannot be resized. This is true for Solang and solc solidity. However, Solang uses a heap, and has a realloc() function. Thus it is is possible for Solang to support pop() and push() on memory arrays.

Note that push and pop already supported on contract storage arrays. Also, arrays are stored in struct vectors in Solang, which are allocated with malloc.

Steps:

In method call add some code to detect "push" and "pop" call on memory arrays. This should result in a new Expression::DynamicArrayPush() and Expression::DynamicArrayPop(). Note that push() with no arguments should return a reference to the new element.
In the code emitter, some code is needed to emit code for Expression::DynamicArrayPush() and Expression::DynamicArrayPop(). Both of these will new to call realloc() to resize the array, and of course pop needs to return the last element and push the new element.
The call return value of realloc() might be a new pointer if the memory was be moved. The array variable will need to be updated.
An alternative implementation would generate a Expression::DynamicArrayResize() for the code emitter.
Arrays can be the bytes type, or every type followed by [], so int64[], address[], struct-foo[], enum-bar[]. All types will need test cases like the one below.

```
contract c {
        function test() public {
                bytes foo = new bytes(1);

                foo[0] = 128;
                foo.push(64);

                assert(foo.length == 2);

                assert(foo[1] == 64);

                assert(64 == foo.pop());

                assert(foo.length == 1);
        }
         }
```

Comment: There is no question here!

Comment: How use push and pop on memory arrays

Comment: Declare it outside the function.

Comment: You have to consider that: using memory might be expensive inside the EVM (costs are cuadratic); it will require extra 'runtime' bytecode to manage reallocations.

Comment: Check this [link](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.6/060-breaking-changes.html?highlight=push)